# Infinite sum with factorial in denominator, exponential function in numerator, multiplied with monomial

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, factorial

In practicing for actuarial exam P I came across a problem where I needed
the value of the sum,
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n \cdot(1.5^n)}{n!}$$
but I don't know where to begin approaching this, the extra n in the
numerator has really thrown me off

Comment: Hint: what is $\frac{n!}{n}$? $\frac{n}{n!}$ is just the inverse of this. (It may also help you to rewrite $(1.5)^n$ as $1.5\times(1.5)^{n-1}$..)

Comment: Hint: $n! = 1\cdot2\cdot3\cdots(n-1)\cdot n$ and $(1.5)^n = 1.5\cdot (1.5)^{n-1}$.

Answer (score 4):

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n(1.5)^n}{n!}=1.5\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1.5^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}=1.5\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1.5^n}{n!}=1.5\times e^{1.5}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Consider 
$$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{nx^n}{n!}=x+x^2+\frac{x^3}{2!}+\frac{x^4}{3!}+\cdots=$$
$$x\left(1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}+\cdots \right)=xe^x.$$
Now plug $x=1.5$:
$$f(1.5)=1.5e^{1.5}.$$